# Twitter Bootstrap - slide a Span left/right

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I'm using twitter bootstrap spans to form two columns in a grid layout. I want to enable the user to close the left-most span so the right span fills the viewport. I've done this by hiding the left panel and changing the width of the right panel and that works fine. However I'd prefer to have the left panel slide closed and the right panel width change to fill the remaining space. The best I've come up with so far is:

```
if ( show )
    $('.content-panel').css( { width: '76.6%' } );

$('.left-panel').animate( {width: 'toggle'}, function(){
    if ( !show )
        $('.content-panel').css( { width: '100%' } );
});
```

where .content panel is the right hand column. This sort of works but looks pretty clunky. It really needs both spans to resize together. Any suggestions most welcome.

Comment: To clarify, are the two columns (which you want to manipulate) in separate Bootstrap columns?

Comment: David, yes. I have:  <div class="span12"><div class="span3"></div> <div class="span9"></div></div> The span3 column is the left column I want to slide closed.

Comment: nevf - I'm guessing you mean to start that with <div class="row">, so it's `<div class="row"><div class="span3"></div> <div class="span9"></div></div>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For fun I hacked Voodoo's example and used the Javascript to manipulate the classes, then CSS transitions to manage the animation: 
http://jsfiddle.net/WDV69/29/

Not necessarily a better solution, just different.

Appologies if my javascript is a bit rough, it's not really my department.

```
$("#closeTrigger").click(function() {

$('.container').removeClass('openLeft').addClass('closeLeft');  
});

$("#openTrigger").click(function() {
$('.container').removeClass('closeLeft').addClass('openLeft');  
});
```

Comment: David, many thanks, that worked beautifully. I had to do a few tweaks, but all is good. Using .closeLeft/.openLeft for the buttons as well as the .container caused some initial head scratching.

Comment: I'm pleased this was helpful. If needed you could refine this by using  @media requests to tweak the behaviour on a fluid grid at wide and narrow screens

Comment: I am using fluid grids - could you explain more re. @media requests

Comment: Much cleaner @DavidTaiaroa, well done. Note -- the CSS3 animation doesn't work in IE9 and below, but the fallback seems to work just fine in IE.

Comment: @nevf re media requests. The bootstrap grid changes depending on the width of the visitors browser window. BS does this by specifying certain CSS properties which are only acitvated at specific browser window widths by using [at]media requests. If you look in the BS CSS files you will see entries like [at]media (max-width: 767px) { something for tablets here }. I'll start you an example when I get a chance.

Comment: @Voodoo re IE < 10 . Yes you are correct. I had forgotten that, thanks for pointing it out. I don't have easy access to IE so good to know that the fallback is OK

Answer (score 4):

Here's a quick solution that seems to accomplish what you want. See [the fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mark47/5DV5X/).

It starts with the Bootstrap span classes for width and then on click, animates the expansion of the width of the right box while reducing the size of the left box and then hiding it completely. I tinkered with adding span12 after the animation is complete.

```
$("#moveTrigger").click(function() {
  // Left box animates to 0 width
  $(".leftbox").animate({ "width": "0%" }, "slow", function() {
    // Hide when width animation finishes
    $(this).hide();
  });
  // Right box expands. Tinkered with add span12 after animation is complete
  $(".rightbox").animate({ "width": "90%" }, "slow", function() {
    $(this).removeClass('span6').addClass('span12').css('width','');
  });
});​
```

This probably requires some refinement, but accomplishes the effect.

Comment: @voodoo - thanks, that was helpful however the animation was sluggish and looked terrible and there was an issue with the rightbox not resizing correctly that I couldn't resolve. David's code works well, so that's great.

Answer (score 0):

As requested, another solution that is responsive:
http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/pwP5V/

Again this is based on the javascript started by @Voodo

It uses media requests to manage the animation, so if you look in the CSS you'll see a bunch of settings like

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
.to-hide {
background-color: yellow;  
}
....
}
```

It still requires some fine-tuning but I think you need real life content to play with at this point because some settings may be dependent on the relative heights of your left and right columns.

There is no end of customisation that you can do. For example check how the close works at the narrowest window. Transition timing could also be customised for opening as well as closing, and for different window sizes as well.

There should be enough here to keep you going for a while!